# DEV looks great,on Staging and PROD I am getting a CS1061 error ('ASP.B' does not contain a definition for 'Prop1')

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I have web user control A that uses another web user control B. Inside A I have:

```
<prefixABC:b ... Prop1="value" />
```

This prop1 is a public property defined on B.ascx:

```
<script runat="server">
...
public string Prop1 { get; set; }
...
</script>
```

Note: I know I wasn't supposed to be using code inside ascx file but it's an internal requirement :/

I also have different environments: dev, staging, prod. They are basically the same (not identical, but very similar). The thing is on dev it works fine, but on staging and prod I am getting this error message:

*Exception type: HttpParseException 
Exception message: d:...\A.ascx(6): error CS1061: 'ASP.B' does not contain a definition for 'Prop1' and no extension method 'Prop1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.B' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I am 100% sure that the code is the same on all environments. Could anyone tell me what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you insert the full control tag, plus the control registering

Comment: I figured it out what the problem was. I didn't have access to the PROD environment so I didn't know what files were there. The thing is there was a version of the control B inside the same folder structure (a couple folders up actually) that wasn't supposed to be there and that was conflicting with the correct one. When I removed it, things started working beautifully.

Comment: Hey, answer your own question and accept it. Lets people know that they don't need to look at the question since it's been answered. Point of order.

Comment: Hi Cyberherbalist, good idea :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what the problem was. I didn't have access to the PROD environment so I didn't know what files were there. The thing is there was a version of the control B inside the same folder structure (a couple folders up actually) that wasn't supposed to be there and that was conflicting with the correct one. When I removed it, things started working beautifully.